# Background image .png that it isn't display correctly with IE8 on the Windows XP

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, iepngfix

I used a background with a image of a '*cloud of ice*', that I do disappearing and then reappearing with jQuery and using the **.fadeTo()** function. As the background image is a **.png**, if you use the **IE8** on the SO **Windows xp** I see the background image as if it is bordered with black/grey color and the transparent isn't perfect, while if you are using the **other browsers** the 'cloud of ice' **is normal**. I would know if there is some plug-in jQuery or css filter that can resolve this transparent incompatibility that there is on IE8.

html:

```
<div class="ice"></div>
```

css:

```css
#main #slogan #iphone .ice {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:22px;
    display:block;
    width:450px;
    height:486px;
    background:transparent url(../images/system/main-animation-ice.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(o).delay(i*'1200').fadeTo(2000,1.0).fadeTo(2000,0.2);
```

On the left there is the normal effect, and on the right there is the IE8 bug.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in CSS by using IE's proprietary filtering system.

```
 #main #slogan #iphone .ice {
     position:absolute;
     top:20px;
     right:22px;
     display:block;
     width:450px;
     height:486px;
     background:url(../images/blank.gif), transparent url(../images/system/main-animation-ice.png) no-repeat 0 0;
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true',sizingMethod='scale',src='../images/system/main-animation-ice.png');
     z-index:1;
 }
```

you will need to use a blank.gif for the 'first' image in your background declaration. This is simply to confuse ie8 and prevent it from using both the filter and the background you have set, and only use the filter. Other browsers support multiple background images and will understand the background declaration and not understand the filter, hence using the background only.

You may also need to play with the `sizingMethod` in the filter to get it to work the way you want.

**UPDATE**

I checked out your site in ie8 and you have more of a problem here than you mentioned in this post.

First you did not include an override of `background : none` so ie8 is giving you BOTH a filter version and a broken background version right now.

Second you are not just using it as a background image, its a sprite. You cannot use a sprite with an alpha image loader; because there is not background position property. So you will need to break it into 3 images and switch between them in the filter rather than switching using background position.

Third animation performance is terrible. You are asking ie8 to alter the opacity of 6 transparent images on top of each other at the same time. Even with the alphaImageLoader, this is going to crash someone's browser.

My advice. For ie8 `$('.ice').hide();`

**However this method for fixing png's in ie8 DOES work http://jsfiddle.net/ZSYbU/2/**

Comment: However I used two style sheet, the first  for all browser and the second only for IE, in the case I must use some hack or special fiter:

 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/styles.css"/>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/styles-ie.css"/><![endif]-->`

Comment: I found a similar solution on the web but it doesn't work this DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader and I don't understand the motive. In teory should be correct.

Comment: @MatteoGilardoni if you use the double stylesheet solution, you may put the filter declaration only on the ie stylesheet, but then you will also need `background: none;`.

Comment: @MatteoGilardoni you may also want to look at your path in the filter `src` ie is weird and picky and does not use the same conventions it its filters that normal css does. You may want to try an absolute path starting with `/` instead of `../`

Comment: So I should write this
`#main #slogan #iphone .ice {
 background:none;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true',sizingMethod='scale',src='http://matteowebdesigner.com/test/yesimove/images/system/main-animation-ice.png');
}`

Comment: @MatteoGilardoni that should do it. You might still need to play with the sizingMethod

Comment: I think that is better use sizingMethod='image' because I mustn't resize the images. Then I will install Virtual Box for to see if this code work it. Because in this moment I am in England (I am italian) and I have only the laptop for work. However if you want see if the code work it you can use this link http://matteowebdesigner.com/test/yesimove/

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there are ways to avoid this Opacity animation issue in IE 8. I have encountered it as well and have never found a solution. If there is one, I'd love to learn it.

Comment: I have added a demo to my answer to demonstrate how filters will fix opacity animation in ie8!